# MVC4 render item that uses variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC, in my View I have :

```
@{
    MyObjectType myNameObject=getMyNameObject();
 }

<p>
   Name : @myNameObject.firstName
</p>
```

Trying to implement desing when line "Name : @myNameObject.firstName"  comes from database through Model or ViewBag  and still pick up value of @myNameObject.firstName. Is that possible?
Thank you

Comment: It is possible. Pass it as a part of a model from controller

Comment: I did try to use model, I get "Name : @myNameObject.firstName" rendered and not "Name : John". Model has item = "Name : @myNameObject.firstName"

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller action method should get the data and pass it to the View. Using a ViewModel is usually the way to go, but ViewBag also works for one-off data. Something like this:

```
// View model.
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

// Controller method.
public ActionResult MyPage()
{
    MyViewModel model = serviceLayer.GetMyData();
    return View(model);
}

// MyPage View.
@model MyViewModel
<p>Name: @Model.Name</p>
```

Comment: I need "Name : @myNameObject.firstName" to be available in another view for Edit by user, meaning users can see "Name: " and be able to change it to "First Name :" for example. And the line "Name : @myNameObject.firstName" should come from database into these two views, so if it will be changed, than both views will reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

your Model:

```
 public class MyNameObject
{
    public MyNameObject()
    {
        //getvalues from database
        //this.FirstName = yourObjectFromDatabase.FirstName;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

in your views that you want to show the first name:

```
 @using WebApplication1.Models; //put it at the top of the view
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("FirstName", new MyNameObject());  }
```

your view:

```
      @model WebApplication1.Models.MyNameObject
      @{
          ViewBag.Title = "FirstName";
       }

       <h2>Name : @Model.FirstName</h2>
```